# Azure AD authentication with CloudFront

Tags: heroku, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, amazon-cloudfront

I have a dynamic website hosted on Heroku and I am using Azure AD for authentication using oAuth 2.0.
I am trying to do Dynamic Whole site delivery using CloudFront.

During authentication, during the step when Azure AD server sends me the authorization code, I am getting a set-cookie in response headers when I run the authentication on Heroku (when I access the website using the Heroku URL)
But when I try to access the website using the CloudFront URL, I'm not getting the set-cookie in response header during the step when Azure AD server sends me the authorization code, hence my authentication logic is breaking.
Why is it so?

Comment: Can you tell us, what is the cookie that you expecting in the response header ?